# MVC & Jquery Mobile with YouTube

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have an MVC application and it's designed for JQM.

However, when I embed a youtube video I get the following error.

```
This content cannot be displayed in a frame 
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.
What you can try:
Open this content in a new window
```

Here is my code;

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="PositionImage" runat="server">
    <div class="videoPlayer" id="PlayerPanel">
        <embed enablejsapi=1 id="player1" width="300"  src="http://youtu.be/_Nng-Ri4c2U" frameborder="0" allowscriptaccess="always" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="PositionImage" runat="server">
    <div class="videoPlayer" id="PlayerPanel">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_Nng-Ri4c2U" width="300" height="190"></iframe>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Rather than use an `<embed />` tag, just use an `<iframe />` instead.